# android - Xmlns:android Problem

Tags: android

For Every Layout xml file contains this instruction at First Layout (xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android") once is enough or we need to put every Layout in the xml file.
Like this

```
 <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        ------------
        --------->
        <Textview
           ---------/>
         <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            ------------
            --------->  
            <ListView
                --------------
                ---------------/>
         </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: i am putting the xml file but it doesn't show why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each xml file , in the root layout you have to set this property:

**xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android** .

**NOTE:** Only in the root container layout of each XML file not in all containers.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: But in some cases i am not putting this. my application will be force to close.

Comment: Suppose my child layout contains the list view then i am getting this problem.

Comment: Might be you are getting force close for some other reason , can you post your code for each you are getting this kind of error.

Comment: No, I dont think that will give you any kind of error. Please check your code nicely once again.

Comment: My application have one child Linear Layout. Initially it is empty. i am adding the List view pro-grammatically to the child Linear layout. this time my application is force to close. i am putting the xmlns statement then this problem is solved. why?